# DeadLock between insert and update

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have 2 methods annoted

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
```

The method runs in parallel

- Method 1) insert rows in table A
- Method 2) update rows in table A

But sometimes I have a deadlock between 2 queries : 1 insert and 1 update.

I don't undertand why I get this LockAcquisitionException because when I check the sql profiler the insert query and the udpate query have nothing in common => I am not trying to update and insert the same row (id values are different).

Why and how could this happend ?

thanks !

[image]

Comment: Why do you use READ_UNCOMMITTED isolation level for transactions? It's definitively not recommended for inserts/updates. Use instead READ_COMMITTED.

Comment: Try looking at SELECT OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) FROM sys.partitions WHERE partition_id =  72057594051624960; to find what the associated object is

Comment: You may have a lock on updating the index

Comment: @IgorMicev its to go faster, I have multiple thread that can insert in the same table, And the method 1) can insert a lot of data with a transaction lasting up to 10minutes. I don't want lock the application .

Comment: @SteveFord the objectId is the table itself, updating the index can the problem, I have 6 index on the tables, but the profiler isn't mentionning any, just the table

Comment: How may rows are being updated / inserted? Is it possible that lock escalation is happening? What does the sys.dm_tran_locks view show?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by disabling the PAGE_LOCK on the index

```
WITH (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF)
```

I realized that I had :

Transaction 1
updating table A then updating table B

Transaction 2
updating table B then updating table A

Dead locking each other (because Transaction 1 was long ~5minutes)

> T1 lock page X on table A
>
> T2 lock page Y on table B
>
> T2 request lock page X on table A and wait
>
> (later T1  want to update table B)
>
> T1 request lock page Y on table B => dead lock

Comment: In your question you only talk about it deadlocking on Updating and Inserting a single table, but in your answer you talk about two tables.  Please adjust the question to say there are two tables, since your solution doesn't answer the question